# Obtener lista de nodos hijos en XML

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

Tengo un problemilla con un ejercicio de Python en el que tengo que usar un fichero XML, el enunciado es este:

> En una lista tenemos distintos identificadores de provincias, mostrar el nombre de las provincias y todos los municipios correspondientes a los identificadores que se encuentran en la lista.

El fichero en cuestión es muy largo pero os pongo un fragmento para que podáis ver mas o menos lo que hay que llevar a cabo:

```
<lista>

   <provincia id="01">

      <nombre>Alava</nombre>

   <localidades>

     <localidad c="0">Aberasturi</localidad>
     <localidad c="0">Abetxuko</localidad>
     <localidad c="0">Abezia</localidad>
     <localidad c="0">Abornikano</localidad>
     <localidad c="0">Acebedo</localidad>

   <provincia id="02">

      <nombre>Barcelona</nombre>

   <localidades>

     <localidad c="0">ej1</localidad>
     <localidad c="0">ej2</localidad>
     <localidad c="0">ej3</localidad>
     <localidad c="0">ej4</localidad>
     <localidad c="0">ej5</localidad>
```

La cosa es que necesito sacar el formato:

```
 Provincia: Alava 01

 Localidades:

 Aberasturi 01
 Abetxuko 01
 Abezia 01

 etc...
```

y así con cada provincia, pero no se como hacerlo. He conseguido sacar las provincias con sus respectivas localidades pero no soy capaz de sacar el `id` de cada provincia y que lo imprima después de su nombre y sus propias localidades.

Os dejo mi código y a ver si alguien puede echarme una mano:

```
from lxml import etree

doc = etree.parse('provinciasypoblaciones.xml')
raiz=doc.getroot()

for i in range(len(raiz)):
    provincia=raiz[i]
    print(provincia[0].text)

    for j in range(len(provincia[1])):
        print(provincia[1][j].text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pues la idea la tienes ya, solo necesitas acceder a los atributos , usando el el diccionario `attrib` de cada nodo por ejemplo.

Te recomiendo no usar `range` e indexación para recorrer una lista, en su lugar usa `for in`, es más eficiente y más legible. Una posibible opción para obtener lo que quieres sería:

```
from lxml import etree

doc = etree.parse('provinciasypoblaciones.xml')
raiz=doc.getroot()

for provincia in raiz:
    nombre, localidades = provincia.getchildren()
    print('\nProvincia: {} {}\n  Localidades:'.format(nombre.text, provincia.attrib['id']))
    for localidad in localidades:
        print('    {} {}'.format(localidad.text, provincia.attrib['id']))
```

Que para tu xml ejemplo (corrigiendo el cierre de las etiquetas) nos mostraría:

```
Provincia: Alava 01
  Localidades:
    Aberasturi 01
    Abetxuko 01
    Abezia 01
    Abornikano 01
    Acebedo 01

Provincia: Barcelona 02
  Localidades:
    ej1 02
    ej2 02
    ej3 02
    ej4 02
    ej5 02
```

Comment: Perfecto! muchas gracias por la ayuda! me apunto el consejo :)